# ng2-search-filter is giving error in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to implement search functionality in my ionic app.

I installed ng2-search-filter by using:

```
   npm i ng2-search-filter --save
```

I added it in page module file:

```
  import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from "ng2-search-filter";

  @NgModule({
     imports: [
       CommonModule,
       FormsModule,
       IonicModule,
       ServiziPageRoutingModule,
       ComponentsModule,
       Ng2SearchPipeModule,
      ]
```

I added a component in page app-fornitservizi and when I use the code in my component:

```
<ion-item
*ngFor="let item of data| filter: searchQuery.value"
lines="none"
 >
```

I get error message:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The pipe 'filter' could not be found!

I am not able to figure it out what is the issue. I would like to know how can I use a pipe in a component while the component is in the page. If anyone knows then please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of **page.module.ts** file import **ng2-search-filter** into **components.module.ts** then it will work. Add following code in your **components.module.ts** file:

**first import Ng2SearchPipeModule:**

```
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from "ng2-search-filter";
```

**Second add Ng2SearchPipeModule to imports in NgModule:**

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
     Ng2SearchPipeModule,
   ]
```